# Disable up/down icon from table header using Tablesorter, instead of hiding it

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

Following is the image of a table using Tablesorter.js to sort the content. When we click on the table header, it will sort accordingly, but same time only the current sort order icon will be displayed. The other will be hidden from the view.

[image]

What I need is, only disable the icon which is not active, ie disable UP arrow if the sorting is Descending and vice-versa.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/atj393/53ofrbss/ @SmitRaval

Comment: "What I need is, only disable the icon which is not active, ie disable UP arrow if the sorting is Descending and vice-versa." Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: When I click on the table header for sorting, two arrows are there right, up and down, one is getting hidden based on the order. I do not want to hide it, just want to reduce the opacity of the inactive arrow.

Comment: Check my answer. Let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. In your css add two classes

```
thead th.up {
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjI8Bya2wnINUMopZAQA7);
}
thead th.down {
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjB+gC+jP2ptn0WskLQA7);
}
```

Replace background-image with the images you want to display i.e up and down arrow with up arrow disabled and vice-versa.

Now in your js code.

```
$('table').tablesorter({

    // customize header HTML
    onRenderHeader: function(index) {
        // the span wrapper is added by default
        this.wrapInner('<span class="icons"></span>');
    },
    cssAsc: 'up',
    cssDesc: 'down',
});
```

cssAsc and cssDesc will add 'up' and 'down' class respectively.

[Documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#Configuration)

It will do the job for you.In my jsfiddle you can see classes getting add on sorting.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/53ofrbss/10/)